# Does one-to-one relationship include foreign key column inside one of the two tables?

Tags: database, one-to-one

I have two tables - `Days` and `Schedules` - that are in a one-to-one relationship. After configuration and creating the database tables, should the `Days` table include `ScheduleId` column on not?

The code is following:

```
public class Day
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int dtDay { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

}

public class Schedule
{
    [ForeignKey ("Day")]
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public int Treatment { get; set; }
    public int PatientCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Day Day { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: Does the `Days` table have to have a `ScheduleId` column inside, because right now with these annodations, i don't see a `ScheduleId` column in my `Days` table.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, sometimes it's easier to reason through it by framing the question in terms of a **parent-child** relationship.  This often takes the form of "[parent entity] {possessive verb} [child entity]". For example: "*Customer has order*"  or "*vendor owns delivery trucks*".

In this case, it is clear that "*Schedule has days*" because days are a natural way to subdivide a schedule. Schedule is the parent entity. Can it go the other way? Does it make sense in the context of your application to say "Days {something} schedules" ? It might, it really depends on how you are planning to use this data in a wider context.

I would consider whether this is really a 1-to-1 relationship. Does each schedule record correspond to exactly one day? Is a day allocated to one and only one schedule? Again, it depends on the overall design and how these tables fit in the larger context. My feeling is that this may actually be a **many-to-many** relationship: a day can have multiple events scheduled; and an event can span more than a single day.

Comment: Thanks Z4-tier for your thorough reply! It was helpful. Still I feel that in this case the relationship might be one-to-one, because i have a custom calendar built which displays days as a usual calendar, but each day also displays patient count and treatment count. So I thought that it might be easier and reasonable to make it so that each day has only one schedule (which in turn has patientcount and treatment properties). Would that make sense?